# Show Font-Style in a Combobox in it's own style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have two comboboxes.

1. for FontFamily.
2. for FontWeight.

Xaml for 1st Combobox looks like:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FontFamily}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In the output of the above XAML I can see all the font-names in its own style. I want to do something similar for 2nd combobox also. Currently I have some items in 2nd combobox as below:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
    <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Normal"/>
    <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Italic"/>
    <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Oblique"/>
</ComboBox>
```

How can I show each item in above combobox in its own style using Combobox.ItemTemplate or something similar without styling each item.

For e.g. my output should look something like:

Normal

*Italic*

*Oblique*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of type converters: for most properties there's a converter that converts a string to a suitable value for the property. It's needed to be able to parse XAML (which is all strings) to types (think of writing something like `Width="Auto"` while remembering that `Width` is a `double` value).

So, you can use something like this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"
                        FontStyle="{Binding }" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <system:String>Normal</system:String>
    <system:String>Italic</system:String>
    <system:String>Oblique</system:String>
</ComboBox>
```

The binding for `FontStyle` sets a string and then type converter springs into action and converts the string to an actual `FontStyle` value to be used by the property.

NOTE: this might not work in .NET 3.0/3.5

**EDIT :** just remembered, in .NET 3.0/3.5, if there's a converter defined for the binding, then type converter is not working - the binding expects the converter to return the right type for the property. Not sure if it was changed in .NET 4.0/4.5 (probably not, and ,IMHO, shouldn't have - need to check it to verify).

Oh, and add this xmlns: `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`